# PySpark: counting rows based on current row value

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with a column "Speed". 
Can I efficiently add a column with, for each row, the number of rows in the DataFrame such that their "Speed" is within +/2 from the row "Speed"?

```
results = spark.createDataFrame([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],
                                 [4],[5],[4],[5],[6],
                                 [5],[6],[1],[3],[8],
                                 [2],[5],[6],[10],[12]], 
                                 ['Speed'])

results.show()

+-----+
|Speed|
+-----+
|    1|
|    2|
|    3|
|    4|
|    5|
|    4|
|    5|
|    4|
|    5|
|    6|
|    5|
|    6|
|    1|
|    3|
|    8|
|    2|
|    5|
|    6|
|   10|
|   12|
+-----+
```

Comment: Could you add a sample of the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a window function :

```py
# Order the window by speed, and look at range [0;+2]
w = Window.orderBy('Speed').rangeBetween(0,2)

# Define a column counting the number of rows containing value Speed+2
results = results.withColumn('count+2',F.count('Speed').over(w)).orderBy('Speed')
results.show()

+-----+-----+
|Speed|count|
+-----+-----+
|    1|    6|
|    1|    6|
|    2|    7|
|    2|    7|
|    3|   10|
|    3|   10|
|    4|   11|
|    4|   11|
|    4|   11|
|    5|    8|
|    5|    8|
|    5|    8|
|    5|    8|
|    5|    8|
|    6|    4|
|    6|    4|
|    6|    4|
|    8|    2|
|   10|    2|
|   12|    1|
+-----+-----+
```

**Note :** The window function counts the studied row itself. You could correct this by adding a -1 in the count column

```py
results = results.withColumn('count+2',F.count('Speed').over(w)-1).orderBy('Speed')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try :-). I was desperately looking for solutions with F.when() and it was really cumbersome.

Comment: Would you have a tip, if the speed range I am looking at is decimal? Like speed within +/-0.5? I get a "Method rangeBetween([class java.lang.Double, class java.lang.Double]) does not exist" error

Comment: Indeed, it looks like `pyspark.sql.Window.rangeBetween` takes only integers as arguments. You could then multiply your speed column by 10, and work on range +/-5. `df = df.withColumn("speed_bis" F.col("Speed")*10)`

Comment: Yes, thanks, it is what I just did and it seems to work. I validate the answer.